# Best C# bindings for Qt?

Tags: c#, qt, binding

I've written a game in C# with SDL.NET and OpenGL. I want to add a menu to it, for which I need Qt. What bindings do you recommend for Qt in C#?

- [Qyoto](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Qyoto)? (apparently it's still unstable in Windows.)
- [qt4dotnet](http://code.google.com/p/qt4dotnet/)?
- other?

Requirements:

- fast
- should just work and be polished - i.e. no weird problems at every step
- integration with the buildsystem, uic, resources, etc, should work well

In fact I'd appreciate any experiences that you can share about using Qt with C#.

**Edit:** I'm now in the middle of a major project using qt4dotnet together with OpenTK. Feel free to ask me questions.

Comment: I once used qt4dotnet and I was quite happy with it.

Comment: Sorry for the necroposting but: how did it work out for you?

Comment: 4 years later, what's the status on this?

Comment: I may be biased, but I think my approach to integrating .NET with Qml only is the best solution. It is actually quite nice! https://github.com/pauldotknopf/net-core-qml

Answer (score 9):

I think the QT Bindings for C#/.NET are not working like you wanna have it. The main problem is that there is no real community which is continuing work on these projects.

**EDIT**: The QTSharp project is getting some love and I think, this could be something to work with (Link: https://github.com/ddobrev/QtSharp)

Comment: I agree.  Take a look around at the major OSS .Net & Mono apps.  I don't see any examples of Qt .Net apps.  It's just not happening.

Comment: I agree, and it makes me sad.

Comment: The Qyoto project seems to be back in development.

Answer (score 2):

Have You looked at [QtSharp](https://github.com/ddobrev/QtSharp)? Seems project is in development.

Comment: As of 2017, this seems to be the most current and supported project.

Comment: Please have a look at my Qml integration with .NET: https://github.com/pauldotknopf/net-core-qml

I believe it is a more robust solution than QtSharp because it involves a custom native layer to ensure memory safety in the cross-talk.