# Can we use QT with C# to create GUI?

Tags: c#, c++, qt

I'm new to C# and I just need to know whether we can use QT to create nice GUI with C#. I know that QT support C++. But what about C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best C# bindings for Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023362/best-c-sharp-bindings-for-qt)

Comment: You might want to take a look at a project I wrote: https://github.com/pauldotknopf/net-core-qml

Answer (score 24, accepted):

.Net C# and QT are totally different frameworks but there is [.Net binding for QT](https://gitlab.com/ddobrev/QtSharp)

My advice is do not combine frameworks they can introduce so many issues, as you said that you are a beginner you can learn [Telerik UI](http://www.telerik.com/devcraft) for nice user interface

**EDIT:**

If you are going to combine them regardless of the suggestions not to, then at the very least, do so in places where it would make the most sense. Write a particular "layer" using one framework over another. For instance, write your GUI in QT, but write your Data and/or Business Logic layer in C#, etc... That would be about the lowest level I would go in trying to combine disparate frameworks. **Gmiley** is right, I did the same thing when I was working on [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc)

Comment: If you are going to combine them regardless of the suggestions not to, then at the very least, do so in places where it would make the most sense. Write a particular "layer" using one framework over another. For instance, write your GUI in QT, but write your Data and/or Business Logic layer in C#, etc... That would be about the lowest level I would go in trying to combine disparate frameworks.

Comment: @gmiley I added your suggestion as is because it has perfect wording and saved my time, you are welcome to edit this answer.

Comment: There is a new project (I wrote) available for Qml integration with .NET. Keep your GUI in Qml and business in .NET.

https://github.com/pauldotknopf/net-core-qml

Comment: Very interesting, seeing [QtSharp](https://github.com/ddobrev/QtSharp)... The recommendations just specify x86 (32bit) compiling... However, integrating with other dependencies (additional dlls, as in my case), implementation must utilize x64 compiling... Hmm... fun times

Comment: Telerik UI is not free and cost a ridiculous amount of money

Comment: "My advice is do not combine frameworks they can introduce so many issues" a lie. QT is like any other C lib.

Answer (score 0):

official Qt project support below languages:
c++,Qml(Quick project), Html ,CSS,JavaScript,JSON,xml
//i note html,css,json,xml  are not language programming ,are Contract

other branches:

project Qt Jambi - Official Site
[jambi](http://www.qtjambi.org)  for java programing

PyQt - for Python  programming
https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt

for C# robust project i didn't see.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can certainly use QT in C# via its binding, but this will not be a managed solution. The main reason to use QT in your project, is if you are building a cross-platform application in C#. If this is your task, you can consider using Nevron Open Vision for .NET (https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision.aspx) - this is a managed C# only cross-platform GUI that will help you seamlessly deploy your application on Windows (WinForms, WPF), macOS (Xamarin.Mac) and Web (Blazor-WebAssembly).

Comment: I cannot find word "Linux" in your suggestion ))

Answer (score -1):

I'm adding information for the beginning of 2023.

At the moment, for creating cross-platform applications, there is a convenient **MAUI** interface for C#. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: MAUI is not a "convenient" framework though...

Comment: @MatsW I still don't know how to use MAUI, I hate anything that requires me to use Visual Studio instead of Visual Studio Code